# What is the best way to parse a single part of a version number into a Version type

Tags: c#

**Context:** I want to parse a single part as string into a Version type:

```
string lVersionAsString = "6";
```

**Problem:** Parsing a Version number with only a single part results in an Exception:

```
Version lVersion = new Version(lVersionAsString); // Exception
```

Reason: The Version class requires minimum two version parts. E.g. the value `6.1`

So I tried the following simple solution:

```
var lVersionParts = lVersionAsString.Split('.');

if (lVersionParts.Length == 1)
{
    lVersionAsString += ".0";
}

Version lVersion = new Version(lVersionAsString); // Works
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: I like your approach

Comment: Another edge case: what if `lVersionAsString` was `"6.5.4.3.2"`?

Comment: @Corak: good point, [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45320607/284240) to handle that too

Comment: Hi, did any of the answers help you to solve your problem? If so it would be cool to  mark one as accepted. Happy coding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`Version.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Version lVersion;
if (!Version.TryParse(lVersionAsString, out lVersion)) 
    lVersion = new Version(lVersionAsString += ".0");
```

Presuming that the string has a valid version most times, it's better to parse him directly and only use the fallback approach otherwise. You could also use `TryParse` then if you want to be sure.

---

Corak posted an interesting [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45320485/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-a-single-digit-into-a-version-type#comment77603248_45320485):

> Another edge case: what if lVersionAsString was "6.5.4.3.2"?

Here is an approach that handles both cases, it truncates the "mini"-version(s):

```
Version lVersion;
while (!Version.TryParse(lVersionAsString, out lVersion) && lVersionAsString.Length > 0)
{
    string[] versionTokens = lVersionAsString.Split('.');
    if (versionTokens.Length == 1 && !versionTokens[0].All(char.IsDigit)) break; // needed with soemthing like "Foo" as version
    lVersionAsString = versionTokens.Length == 1 
        ? lVersionAsString += ".0" 
        : lVersionAsString.Remove(lVersionAsString.LastIndexOf('.'));
}
```

Comment: I've just noticed the TryParse method too but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 6):

you could simply check whether the number is in the dot format:

```
if(!lVersionAsString.Contains("."))
{
    lVersionAsString += ".0";
}
```

Comment: +1 Will give slightly better performance because it avoids creating an array object.  The equivalent `lVersion.IndexOf('.') == -1` would be even faster, though you'd find it difficult to measure the difference.

Comment: @Joe both methods are O(n). But what do you mean by "+1 Will give slightly better performance because it avoids creating an array object" ? I thought that a string is internally represented by a char array anymway?=! Or am I wrong?

Comment: With the split method of OP as baseline (`1.00`), contains is a bit faster (`0.86`) while indexOf is a lot faster (`0.22`). -- still, we're taking about nanoseconds. :) --- RegEx (static and compiled) isn't good for smaller strings (`3.51`), while an uncompiled and always re-instanciated RegEx is off the charts...

Comment: @MongZhu - I think Joe meant your solution is faster than the split solution in OP because that **split** creates an array object.

Answer (score 0):

You could write this in one line like this.

```
Version lVersion = new Version(lVersionAsString.PadRight(lVersionAsString.Length + lVersionAsString.IndexOf(".") * -1, ".").PadRight(lVersionAsString.Length + lVersionAsString.IndexOf(".") * -1 + 1, "0"));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But an Version number with a single part could be `10`. That will not work with your code.